# Crystal Reports SQL - comparing data in multiple fields for grouping purposes

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I have a database table which contains the following fields (amoung others)

Person 1

Person 2

Person 3

I need to group by Person.  Unfortunately the same person can appear in any one of the above three fields.  I can't simply concatenate the 3 fields as there may be a name in each field ie 3 names in a particular entry.  For example

Record 1   Joe Bloggs (Person 1), Person 2 null, Person 3 null

Record 2  Jane Black (Person 1), Joe Bloggs (Person 2), Person 3 null

Record 3   Jane Black (Person 1), James Blue (person 2), Joe Bloggs (person 3)

Yes I know the database table is set up incorrectly - ideally there should be 1 field for Person's name and multiple entries but this is not the case and this is what I have to work with.

How on earth can I group by name when the answer is in one of several fields ?
Please note I am not looking to pull out a particular name (that would be easy as I would search for the name in either of the 3 fields).  I need to group by name to show a report containing everyone.  The report would look like:

Group 1: Joe Bloggs

Record 1 fields

Record 2 Fields

Record 3 fields

Group 2: Jane Black

Record 2 Fields

Record 3 Fields

Group 3: James Blue

Record 3 fields

Any help would be much appreciated thank you !

Comment: can you show tried query. add sample data with extact output which you want

Comment: I haven't tried a query as I have no idea how to start.  The output I am wanting is shown above.  ie grouped by name and then I can choose the relevant fields from the table that I need.

Comment: Do you have control over database like can you create views?